# Calculate 24 hour time to determine store open/store close

Tags: python, datetime

I am fairly new to Python. I am trying to determine if a store is open or closed based on 24 hour format.
If the store hours (open - close) are 06:00:00 - 22:00:00 then there is not problem with the below code
If the store hours are 06:00:00 - 03:00:00, then I am having trouble figuring out how to calculate it so that both scenarios work.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
gs_StoreOpenHours24 = '06:00:00, 03:00:00'  
tnow = datetime.now().time() #07:54:10.390955  
print('tnow:' + str(tnow))  
#Get the store open/close values  
StoreOpen, StoreClose = gs_StoreOpenHours24.split(',')  
StoreOpen = StoreOpen.strip()  
StoreClose = StoreClose.strip()  

#Format the store open/close to a time format  
StoreOpen = datetime.strptime(StoreOpen, '%H:%M:%S').time() #convert to a time format. 06:00:00  
StoreClose = datetime.strptime(StoreClose, '%H:%M:%S').time() #convert to a time format. #22:00:00  
print('StoreOpen:' + str(StoreOpen))  
print('StoreClose:' + str(StoreClose))  

#check if the store is open or closed  
# if (tnow <= StoreOpen and tnow >= StoreClose) :  
if (StoreOpen <= tnow and StoreClose >= tnow):  
    print('Store Is Open')    
else:  
    print('Store Is Closed')
```

Comment: Variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that close is always after open, so you could check if the parsed close time is after the parsed open time and if not just add a day to close time.

```py
StoreOpen = datetime.strptime(StoreOpen, '%H:%M:%S').time() #convert to a time format. 06:00:00  
StoreClose = datetime.strptime(StoreClose, '%H:%M:%S').time() #convert to a time format. #22:00:00  

if StoreOpen > StoreClose:
   StoreClose += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: Ahhh. Thank you!